# Just updated to Mac OS X 10.9.2 Now Netbeans will not open

Tags: osx-mavericks

I have tried updating Java and even tried re-installing it. Ever since I updated this morning, it will not open. Has anyone else had an issue of a program not opening?

Comment: Updated Java to which version? What version of Netbeans are you using?

Answer (score 0):

I just updated Java SE to 7u51, and I can open Netbeans now.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: I am sorry. I use stackoverflow first time, and I can't leave a comment. I have same issue, so I want to help. I will be careful about that. Thank you.

Comment: @Praveen: why would this not be an answer?

Comment: The question is "has anyone else had an issue"? This answer says "yes, I had the issue; and with the upgrade, the issue has gone away". While it is a very short answer, I believe it is valid.